# Debian: How to get the current loaded kernel package name?

Tags: shell, debian, linux-kernel

With the following command, I can list all the installed kernel package:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

With the following command, I get for instance the version of the current kernel used:

```
$ uname -r
```

However, my needs is to just display in a terminal, the Debian package name corresponding of the current loaded kernel.

As multiples packages names can have the same version, it is difficult to identify uniquely a particular kernel with the previous commands.

So... Do you have an idea to get the package name of the current kernel ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep -o "^linux-image-$(uname -r)"
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
```

or

```
$ dpkg -l | grep -o "linux-image-$(uname -r)"
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic
```

**EDIT:** If you have multiple versions of the same kernel release, run the following `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rel="$(uname -r)"
ver="$(uname -v)"
current="${rel%-*}.${ver:1:2}"
echo "$(dpkg -l | grep -Po "linux-image-${rel}(?=\s+${current})")"
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I setup multiples kernel with same versions but different patches, I'm unable to tell which is the currently loaded one...

Comment: @Tutux: Check my edits..